# Strange SQL Server Error That Only Occurs On One Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ("test value")
```

This works on any other table I make, but I'm trying to insert values into a table someone else made.  I get this strange error and have no idea of what to make of it.  I'm not a MS SQL expert, so I appreciate any help I can get.

```
Msg 4701, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MainPayloadParserTrigger, Line 31
Cannot find the object "DataSplitDB" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger associated with that table? Perhaps it's  trying to call a SP or Function that doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: Yes, I just looked and found that is what was going on.  The table was made to process other data from a different source, so I've got to stop that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the error message. See the `Procedure  MainPayloadParserTrigger` in the message? It appears the other person who created the table has an insert trigger associated with the table and it is causing the error by something it is trying to do.

Comment: I need to leave that trigger there, but I also need to insert data into the table.  Do you know how I can insert data without firing off the trigger in C#?

Comment: Looks like this might be it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163442.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that if you "need to leave the trigger there", but then use `DISABLE TRIGGER`, you are effectively removing it until you enable it again. If this is a development environment, it probably doesn't matter though.